# Python slimit minimizer unwanted warning output

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
from slimit import minify


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("start")

    # Normally, I pass real JavaScript. For this issue, an empty string reproduces problem.
    minify("", mangle=True)

    print("exit")
```

This triggers the following console output.

```
start
WARNING: Couldn't write lextab module <module 'slimit.lextab' from '/Users/kurtostfeld/samba/wrapad/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/slimit/lextab.pyc'>. Won't overwrite existing lextab module
WARNING: yacc table file version is out of date
WARNING: Token 'IMPORT' defined, but not used
WARNING: Token 'BLOCK_COMMENT' defined, but not used
WARNING: Token 'ENUM' defined, but not used
WARNING: Token 'EXTENDS' defined, but not used
WARNING: Token 'LINE_COMMENT' defined, but not used
WARNING: Token 'LINE_TERMINATOR' defined, but not used
WARNING: Token 'CONST' defined, but not used
WARNING: Token 'EXPORT' defined, but not used
WARNING: Token 'CLASS' defined, but not used
WARNING: Token 'SUPER' defined, but not used
WARNING: There are 10 unused tokens
WARNING: Couldn't create <module 'slimit.yacctab' from '/Users/kurtostfeld/samba/wrapad/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/slimit/yacctab.pyc'>. Won't overwrite existing tabmodule
exit
```

These warnings are flooding my application console output. How can I use minify without generating warnings?

I'm using Python 2.7.12, and what is currently the latest library versions: slimit 0.8.1, ply 3.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here was the solution that I went with. I made a custom variant of two slimit functions that pass an extra `errorlog=ply.yacc.NullLogger()` call to the `ply.yacc.yacc` function.

```
class SlimitNoLoggingParser(Parser):
    """
    This is a simple customized variant to slimit.parser.Parser.

    The only difference is that this passes a errorlog=ply.yacc.NullLogger() to ply.yacc.yacc to suppress unwanted
    stderr logging output.
    """

    def __init__(self, lex_optimize=True, lextab=lextab,
                 yacc_optimize=True, yacctab=yacctab, yacc_debug=False):
        self.lex_optimize = lex_optimize
        self.lextab = lextab
        self.yacc_optimize = yacc_optimize
        self.yacctab = yacctab
        self.yacc_debug = yacc_debug

        self.lexer = Lexer()
        self.lexer.build(optimize=lex_optimize, lextab=lextab)
        self.tokens = self.lexer.tokens

        self.parser = ply.yacc.yacc(
            module=self, optimize=yacc_optimize,
            errorlog=ply.yacc.NullLogger(),
            debug=yacc_debug, tabmodule=yacctab, start='program')

        # https://github.com/rspivak/slimit/issues/29
        # lexer.auto_semi can cause a loop in a parser
        # when a parser error happens on a token right after
        # a newline.
        # We keep record of the tokens that caused p_error
        # and if the token has already been seen - we raise
        # a SyntaxError exception to avoid looping over and
        # over again.
        self._error_tokens = {}


# This is a simply variant of slimit.minify that suppresses unwanted noisy stderr logging output.
def warning_free_minify(text, mangle=False, mangle_toplevel=False):
    parser = SlimitNoLoggingParser(lex_optimize=False)
    tree = parser.parse(text)
    if mangle:
        mangler.mangle(tree, toplevel=mangle_toplevel)
    minified = ECMAMinifier().visit(tree)
    return minified
```

Answer (score 5):

According [to this issue on Github](https://github.com/dabeaz/ply/issues/82), slimit depends of the `ply` package. After few tries, it seems that theses warnings appear since version 3.8 of `ply`. . You could update `ply` to 3.6 which is the last version that doesn't bring these messages :

```
pip uninstall ply -y && pip install ply==3.6
```

It solved my problem.

**UPDATE**
Install a sooner version of `ply` was really a bad work around since some of my tests were failing. Original `slimit` version seems not maintained well so I suggest to update to a newer version, [metatoaster  did a good job to improve it](https://github.com/rspivak/slimit/issues/97) and fixed that problem of warning message. The solution for me was to uninstall `slimit` and then install it's version:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/metatoaster/slimit.git#egg=slimit
```

**FINAL UPDATE** In fact, `slimit` seems not maintened anymore and its successor is called `calmjs`, there is few differences but it is really more stable and don't shows these annoying warning message. See: https://github.com/calmjs/calmjs.parse

Comment: ply 3.4 is from 2011. ply 3.11 is from 2018. 3.11 is the newer release: https://pypi.org/project/ply/#history

Comment: Where did you see that `slimit` is not maintained anymore?

Comment: @BeChillerToo don't remember honnestly. I probably did a fake news by mistake,  calmjs seems more active anyway

Comment: @snoobdogg in fact you're probably right. I checked the Github page pour slimit, it has some recent commits, but the last release is from 2013...

Comment: The above url does not work any more, but the following one currently solves the issue: https://github.com/rspivak/slimit

Comment: @jciloa calmjs is a better alternative to slimit. last commit on the repos of your url is from august 2018. Last commit from calmjs repos is janunary 2020

Answer (score 3):

Switching versions did not change anything for me, I found another workaround: simply delete (or move, if you want to be cautious) the mentioned files (`yourpython/site-packages/slimit/yacctab.py` and `yourpython/site-packages/slimit/lextab.py`).

I believe the module will re-create these files and stop bothering you with warning messages.

Answer (score 2):

`Slimit` uses `ply` under the hood, which uses `logging` from stdlib. AFAICS `slimit` does not allow you to pass the logging parameters that `ply`'s `lex` and `yacc` expect.

While you therefor can't (directly) access `ply`'s logging, you should be able to suppress those messages my raising the global logging level:

```
import logging
...
logging.disable(logging.CRITICAL)
minify("", mangle=True)
logging.disable(logging.NOTSET)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this parser, too: https://github.com/PiotrDabkowski/pyjsparser

It works and is easy to use. It does not handle comments though.
(Neither does `calmjs` seems to handle comments fully: Its `parse` function has a parameter to indicate that you want the comments, but as of now, some comments seem to get lost.)